What file format do key-value Linux procFS files use?
I'm most interested in the files which provide system information, like /proc/mdstat, /proc/crypto, and /proc/cpuinfo. /proc/mdstat demonstrates this most concisely:


#!/usr/bin/env sh
cat '/proc/mdstat'



Personalities : 
unused devices: <none>


This is interesting, because you would think that for the sake of parsing, you might always use consistent upper-case characters for the key names and quotation for when there are spaces (like JSON5) or at least consistent application of logical values (like <none>) when there is no data.
This is perplexing. I can't imagine which it actually adheres to.


The rest appear to be a space-delimited equivalent to .TSVs:

major minor  #blocks  name

 259        0 1953514584 nvme3n1
 259        2 1953510400 nvme3n1p1
 259        1 1953514584 nvme1n1
 259        3     614400 nvme1n1p1
 259        4    1048576 nvme1n1p2
 259        5 1951850496 nvme1n1p3
 259        6  250059096 nvme0n1
 259        7  244198584 nvme2n1
 259        8      16384 nvme2n1p1
 259        9  243446784 nvme2n1p2
 259       10     733184 nvme2n1p3
 252        0    8388608 zram0
   7        0          4 loop0
   7        1     106488 loop1
   7        2     106692 loop2
   7        3      65480 loop3
   7        4      65480 loop4
   7        5      75996 loop5
   7        6      76020 loop6
   7        7      71928 loop7
   7        9      71840 loop9
   7        8      93888 loop8
   7       10      39664 loop10
   7       11      39760 loop11
   7       12       2120 loop12


...so they're not of interest.

Those files are simple text files. That should be obvious because you used the cat command to display the contents of those files. The cat command does not perform any formatting or translation; what's in the file is what you see on the terminal screen. What you see is what you get.

@sawdust, that's irrelevant. I can cat a JSON or YAML file, despite it containing structured data.

None. All of them are hand-crafted through a series of seq_printf() calls, with the vague intent of being "machine readable" by someone wielding the C sscanf() (which makes it somewhat convenient to parse a mix of delimited and fixed-width fields) and/or regexes.
Some of them aren't meant to be machine-readable at all, e.g. the "mdstat" file, and/or are legacy interfaces superseded by a more structured system, e.g. the routing tables in /proc/self/net are a very old interface that has long been replaced by Netlink.

That seems like a markedly strange decision. Got any knowledge of why this is so, considering how important this information is?

Ah, your edit mostly answers that.

Many of them have long been superseded by /sys, or by Netlink, or other interfaces. Some are only of interest to humans, while e.g. software only needs to query whether specific algorithms are available, not list all of them. There are indeed a few that remain the only interface and require some annoying parsing (/proc/keys and /proc/locks being the ones I remember – the latter has some ugly gotchas where additional fields may be inserted), but overall /proc isn't the primary place for generic info anymore.

But /proc/keys has a library to parse it so tools generally don't need to touch it directly, and /proc/locks is only useful for human consumption, so only lslocks has to parse it – software that actually uses locking doesn't care. As another example, pretty much anything that has to do with devices can be found in /sys/class with generally one value per 'file' (often accessed through libudev), making the "block devices" table obsolete.

Thanks for that. You're definitely correct about using the dedicated tool for the file - lslocks --json gives me good data, whereas cat /proc/locks would have been Hellish to parse.
